# Windows7のスタートアップのレジストリについて

Tags: windows

(1)HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
(2)HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
(3)HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

質問:
スタートアップへ追加する時のレジストリは上の３つで全部ですか？

これらのレジストリ以外に一緒に追加または変更しなければならないレジストリキーはありますか？

HKLMがローカルマシン全体、
HKCUがユーザー限定、
(2)が64bitOS上で32bitソフトをスタートアップに追加する場合、
という認識であってますか？
あと、32BITのSkypeクライアントが(3)に登録されてるんですが、これはなぜですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> スタートアップへ追加する時のレジストリは上の３つで全部ですか？

質問の意図がよくわかりませんでした。いずれか１ヶ所へ追加すれば実行されます。
ログオン時に実行されるものを把握するという意味でしたら、[システム構成ユーティリティを使用してスタートアップ アプリケーションを把握して制御する](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/magazine/ee851671.aspx)に各種設定が列挙されています。（16bit互換まで含めてかなり種類があるのでここには列挙しません。）

---

> 32BITのSkypeクライアントが(3)に登録されてるんですが、これはなぜですか？

[WOW64 の影響を受けるレジストリ キー](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/aa384253(v=vs.85).aspx)で説明されていますが、

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` は `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` へリダイレクトされます
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE` はリダイレクトされず、64 / 32 で共有されます。

となっているため、32bitアプリケーションであっても `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE` を使います。

Comment: 知りたかったのはmsconfigのスタートアップタブに追加する時に追加しなければならないキーと、32BITと64BITでキーが違うのかの2点で、この回答で全て解決しました。ありがとうございました。